# Styling variables in IPython NB using CSS

Tags: css, jupyter-notebook

I've been working on a port of zenburn for IPython notebook. It's working pretty well so far, but there's one severe limitation. When using zenburn in emacs and assigning a variable, the variable being assigned (i.e. text to the left of the equals sign) is set to orange. My question is: is there a way to perform an equivalent styling using CSS?

A GitHub search for `ipynb-zenburn` will yield a link to the repository containing my work so far. This project is my first exposure to CSS. I apologize if this question has an obvious answer.

Below is a screenshot of my current notebook style:

[ipynb-zenburn example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Skhwf.png)

Compare to zenburn-emacs:

[zenburn-emacs example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgWil.png)